# Change picasa album cover image

Tags: javascript, api, picasa

I have created a demo for showing Picasa albums and images using this [link](http://ahamlett.com/jQuery-Picasa-Gallery/).

Its working fine, but now I want to change cover image of album in Picasa from our site.

Can we do this using javascript and by modifying the code. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems the chosen image is hardcoded as the first picture of the result set from picasa](https://github.com/alanhamlett/jQuery-Picasa-Gallery/blob/master/jquery.picasagallery.js#L75) and cannot be changed via an option.

You will need to dive into JS programming to change the library according to your needs. Adding an option to control which of the items of `media$content` instead of `0` is chosen might be a first start.

Maybe something like

```
var img_src = json.feed.entry[i].media$group.media$content[data.albumcover_number].url.split('/');
```

instead of the code line I linked above, and adding the default option [here](https://github.com/alanhamlett/jQuery-Picasa-Gallery/blob/master/jquery.picasagallery.js#L237)

```
'albumcover_number': 0
```

does the trick.

Comment: But when I change cover image in picasa, it reflect changes in the application. So I want a script that changes cover image in the picasa from the application.

Comment: The Javascript library you chose does not provide this functionality. Also this would be unsafe to do via Javascript. Updating your Picasa albums via API requires a secret authorization token, which you do not want to write into a public accessible Javascript file.

Comment: You can easily achieve your desired result with a server side programming language instead. [There exist some code examples on the Picasa site.](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code), although this requires a little more programming skill.

Comment: This doc is not proper. Can you show me a tutorial link on this.

Comment: I am sorry, I expected the API to support this functionality, but actually it does not. Your request was already acknowledged as [future request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=461&q=label%3AAPI-Picasa&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) and [here is a post concerning this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picasa-data-api/b4eQTXV-rCA).